# Error after upgrade to D10

Tags: 10, upgrading

I am having this error after upgrading to D10.01 from D9.5 . Can someone help, please?

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "node_type" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionManager are: condition_group, response_code, language, non_node_condition, request_path, current_theme, user_role, entity_bundle:block_content, entity_bundle:media, entity_bundle:chart, entity_bundle:node, entity_bundle:redirect, entity_bundle:shortcut, entity_bundle:taxonomy_term, entity_bundle:menu_link_content, entity_bundle:paragraph" at /web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 53